# Magento 2 : How can i read Xml file data

Tags: magento2, xml, data-migration, product-import

I have product file in XML format. I just need to read this file and import those data.

I have already use **simplexml_load_file(file path)** but it will work only small size of file. Is there any other way to read this large XML file ?

Comment: please check my solution and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
 namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;  
      class ParseXmlClass 
         {
                /**
                 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader
                 */
                protected $moduleDirReader;

                /**
                 * @var \Magento\Framework\Xml\Parser
                 */
                private $parser;

                    ...

                public function getValue() 
                {
                    $filePath = $this->moduleDirReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'ModuleName') 
                       . '/yourxml.xml'
                    $parsedArray = $this->parser->load($filePath)->xmlToArray();
                    return $parsedArray['xmlNodeName'];
                }
         }
```

Comment: my code is stuck at line : $this->parser->load. i have not getting false or true value in xml object

Comment: issue only getting while  reading large file around 184MB xml file size

Comment: If you are not getting true and false from code  and also there is no error it mean's the script is running  , So I would recommend to do following :
1. Increase max execution time and and max post file  size , by default it set to 2 MB  increase to 512 MB in php.ini
2. If possible increase you server CPU  or RAM it will help you for faster execution .
Hope solution will work for you .

Comment: Find following value in php.ini
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
memory_limit = 2048M
Then run following command
sudo service apache2 restart (if you are using apache2)
sudo service httpd restart (if you are using nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Totally shooting form the hip here, but have you tried PHP's XMLReader or DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML? SimpleXML loads the full document to memory, while the other two do not.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $parser;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Xml\Parser $parser
) {
    $this->parser = $parser;
}

public function getXMLArrayData()
{
    $filePath = "/var/www/html/mydemosite/pub/media/sitemap/filename.xml";
    $parsedArray = $this->parser->load($filePath)->xmlToArray();

    return $parsedArray;

    //$json = json_encode($parsedArray);
    //$array = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***